# get youtube signatureCipher url

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

i'm trying to find a way to get audio streaming url's from every video on youtube. I managed to get the URL's of some videos parsing json and getting adaptiveFormats url, but most of the videos is using "signatureCipher" and the URL does not work. Is there a way to decode it to get the working audio url in JS ?

Comment: Maybe looking at [the source code](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) of `yt-dlp -g VIDEO_ID` may help you.